# Regex remove multiple whitespace and line-break inside HTML tag

Tags: html, ruby, regex

Some background: we're adding a styleguide to our Middleman project. It's for other developers to use, so we want our code examples to be readable. We don't however want to have to update code in multiple places when we change a component.

We use [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for markdown parsing and creating code examples.

````
<%= partial '../partials/component' %>

```html
    <%= partial '../partials/component' %>
```
````

This does however leave very messy and unreadable code examples. We can clean them up pretty well with [htmlbeautifier](https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlbeautifier). But we still have the issue with multiple whitespaces and linebreaks inside HTML tags.

It often looks like this:

```
<article class="default-s-sans teaser-media"

     data-item-ratio="16x9"


    data-background-color="d-blue"

>
```

We want to remove the extra white space and line breaks inside the tag, that is between `<` and `>`. But not between elements, so it should leave this unchanged:

```
<div>
    <span class="price">$100</span>
    <span>
       Word     word
    </span>
</div>
```

I have gotten [this far](https://regex101.com/r/oMPi8T/1):

```
html.gsub(/(?<=<)(\s{2,})(?>)/, ' ')
```

But it will only match whitespaces between `<` and `>` if there's nothing else between.

How can I match whitespaces between `<` and `>` but allow other characters as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [matchdata object in gsub blocks](http://brettterpstra.com/2014/10/28/the-matchdata-object-in-ruby-gsub-blocks/):

```
html.gsub(/(?<=<)(.+)(?>)/m) { |match| match.gsub(/\n/, ' ').gsub(/\s+/, ' ') }
```

Comment: It might be overly complicated to only have 1 regex, this works much better. I changed the first regex to make sure I only match a single tagg: `/<([^>]+)>/`

Answer (score 0):

[`String#sqeeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-squeeze) comes to the rescue:

> `squeeze([other_str]*)` → `new_str`
>
> Builds a set of characters from the `other_str` parameter(s) using the procedure described for `String#count`. Returns a new string where runs of the same character that occur in this set are replaced by a single character. If no arguments are given, all runs of identical characters are replaced by a single character.
>
> ```
> "yellow moon".squeeze                  #=> "yelow mon"
> "  now   is  the".squeeze(" ")         #=> " now is the"
> "putters shoot balls".squeeze("m-z")   #=> "puters shot balls"
> ```